# Convert a full string (represented in exponential format) back in number in PHP

Tags: php, string, numbers, exponential

I've been searching for converting my exponential number string into an exact number.
So, I've an exponential number stored as string in MySQL. I want to convert back this string in the exact number.
But It seems the number is quite big and crosses the boundary and provide me wrong data.

While I tried following code in various format but result is not in proper format.

```
policy_number = "2.9992020830803E+18";  
number_format($policy_number, 0,'.','');  
// Output  
 2999202083080300032  


(float) $policy_number;  
// Output
2.9992020830803E+18  


sscanf($policy_number, "%f")[0];  
// Output
2.9992020830803E+18  


floatval($policy_number);   
// Output
2.9992020830803E+18  


gmp_init("2.9992020830803E+18");  
gmp_strval($policy_number);  
// Output
0  


"2.9992020830803E+18" + 0;  
// Output
2.9992020830803E+18
```

Please show me the right way to convert it.

Comment: So, what exactly are you *trying* to get as output? If you stored a large integer as a number when it should have been a string—which I'm guessing you did, based on the variable name—you *can't* "convert back" to the integer reliably. You lost information when you stored it as a numeric format.

Comment: I was trying to get 2999202083080300000. If you see in my first attempt it gave an extra 32 don't know why?

Comment: If you are always going to want the number to end with zeros, then converting it to a string is trivial. But, as I’ve already suggested, the real solution here is to store the data as a string, not a number. After all, you’re not interested in an *amount* if this is an identifier number; you’re interested in a particular *string of digits*. You should store the data accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am bit confuse here.
See, I've this policy_number already stored in MySQl  which is a Varchar. ( I can't change this into any other data type as there is a possibility that it may have char as well in the policy number). Now I am trying to retrieve it from Mysql and would like to showcase on HTML. As number is already in exponential format in MYSQL, I tried to convert using number_format function. As I am using PHP, believe it will take care about data type itself. As far as MySQL is concern I can't change the value input as it is already in exponential format.

Comment: Varchar is a reasonable column datatype. Your problem appears to be that you are accidentally converting it to a numeric value either when saving to the database or when retrieving it. It’s impossible to say which because you haven’t provided any code. In any case, this is a clear instance of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/238426); the real problem you have to solve is not converting a number in exponential notation to a simple integer, but avoiding putting your data into that format in the first place.

Comment: OK Thanks for your support.   Will look into the input data. But why number_format function gives that extra 32 in last? Is it because of data range issue or something else?

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @ArunMahajan It’s just how math with floating point values works. There’s inherent imprecision in their storage and use. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 1):

***Updated***

I agree with Ed Cottrell that your problem is how you are storing your data in the db.  However, if this is a project where you are already looking at a large set of data that is already stored as an exponent then this function I wrote should work for you. It should work for positive and negative bases and exponents.  It basically mimics the way you would do the operation by hand.

I was not able to figure out a way to do it using math functions.  If someone knows how to do it better please post.  In the meantime, I had fun writing this.

Hope it helps you out!

```
function getRealNumber($number){

  //Parse the base and exponent.
  preg_match('/^(.*?)E[\-|\+](.*?)$/', $number, $data);

  $base = $data[1];
  $exp = $data[2];

  //Test to see if the base is negative.
  if(preg_match('/\-/', $base)){

    $base = str_replace('-', '', $base);
    $isNegative = TRUE;

  }

  //Capture the offset of the decimal point.
  preg_match('/\./', $base, $position, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

  $offset = $position[0][1]; //This is the offset of the decimal point.
  $string = str_replace('.', '', $base); //Get numbers without decimal.
  $length = strlen($string); //Get the length of string.

  //Test to see if we are adding zeros to the end or beginning of string.
  if(preg_match('/E\+/', $number)){

    //Let's move the decimal.
    if($length > ($exp + $offset)){

      $string = substr_replace($string, '.', ($exp + $offset), 0);

    } else {

      $string = $string . str_repeat('0', $exp - ($length - $offset));

    }


  }elseif(preg_match('/E\-/', $number)){

    //Calculate the number of zeros needed to add and append them.
    if($offset > $exp){

      $string = substr_replace($string, '.', $offset, 0);

    } else {

      $string = '0.' . str_repeat('0', $exp - $offset) . $string;

    }

  }

  //Add the negative sign if we need to.
  if(!$isNegative){

    return $string;

  } else {

    return '-' . $string;

  }

}

$policy_number = "2.9992020830803E+18";
echo getRealNumber($policy_number);

//Will output 2999202083080300000
```

Comment: See if you try to convert 2.9992020830803E+18 into number it should be 2999202083080300000 while out put is 2999202083080300032. That is where I am struggling.

Comment: `if(!$isNegative)` should be `if(!isset($isNegative))`